# How do I set the interlaced flag on an MKV file so that VLC can automatically play it back deinterlaced?

Tags: video-encoding, vlc, mkv, matroska

I've got an MKV file whose source is interlaced NTSC MPEG-2 video. I converted it to H.264 MKV with HandBrake, but this process did not set the "interlaced" flag in the MKV file.  The content *is* interlaced—and I do want it to stay interlaced because it looks much better playing back as 60 fields-per-second content with on-the-fly deinterlacing than it does as 30 frames-per-second content that's been deinterlaced at encode-time.

I tried this...

```
mkvpropedit -e track:v1 -a interlaced=1 foo.mkv
```

which *did* indeed set the interlaced bit...

```
|+ Segment tracks
| + A track
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 704
|   + Pixel height: 480
|   + Display width: 625
|   + Display height: 480
|   + Interlaced: 1
```

But when I play the video with VLC with Deinterlace set to Automatic, it doesn't think the video is interlaced and therefore doesn't do the deinterlacing.

What am I doing wrong?

Software versions:
HandBrake 0.9.5
mkvpropedit v5.0.1
Mac OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Possible [VLC options](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) and search for keywords like `interlace` and `deinterlace`. Maybe some VLC features don't work well under MacOSX for certain VLC version. You can try the nightly build versions of VLC from their website.

Comment: Have you tried VLC itself to transcode your MPEG2 video and save into a file since internally it uses FFmpeg plugin for some of its features.

Answer (score 3):

to make handbrake set the interlaced flag:

-use H.264(x264) Video Codec

-at the bottom of the Advanced Tab add :tff or :bff, ( dependant if source is top field first or bottom field first)

Comment: How do you determine whether the source is top-field-first or bottom-field-first? Trial and error?

Comment: I have tried both to see which one was correct (smooth motion)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying FFMPEG.

Documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

> ‘-ilme’ 
>   Force interlacing support in encoder (MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 only).
>   Use this option if your input file is interlaced and you want to keep
>   the interlaced format for minimum losses. The alternative is to
>   deinterlace the input stream with ‘-deinterlace’, but deinterlacing
>   introduces losses.

Since you mentioned you are on OSX 10.7 you can use MacPorts to install all dependencies + ffmpeg for you (once the deps are installed you can also build the latest from git).

http://www.macports.org/

(*You must be comfortable with the command line for all these tools.*)

Comment: Hmm, ok, so HandBrake lets me set the Video Codec to "MPEG-4 (FFmpeg)".  Is it better to convert MPEG-2 to MPEG-4 than to H.264?  (I'm much more concerned about accuracy than about file size.)

Comment: @ToddLehman If file size doesn't matter, overall it doesn't matter as much. By they way, H264 is mpeg4 (specifically MPEG-4 AVC). But you'll likely have to use a higher bitrate for mpeg4 to achieve the same quality. Someone did a comparison here: http://metroxing.blogspot.com/2006/10/handbrake-mpeg4-or-h264.html